# react-redux: why do I get _this.props.incrementCounter is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Just starting with react/redux. Trying to implement a Counter component hookedup to a action:

```
export class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.props.incrementCounter();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
                hello this is counter:{this.props.counter}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    counter: state
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { incrementCounter })(Counter)
```

This is part of the index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

However when I run the app I get an error when clicking on the 'hello' div?

Error:
_this.props.incrementCounter is not a function

Why am I getting this error, looks like the props are not passed down properly?

For more code see : [github](https://github.com/dimitri-a/redux_practice)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a function as second parameter, like:

`connect(mapStateToProps, dispatch => ({ incrementCounter }))(Counter)`

Comment: where is defined 'incrementCounter'? like in general you will have something like `dispatch => ({ incrementCounter: () => dispatch(methodName()) })

Comment: it is possible that incrementCounter is undefined atm?